# How do I autostart a program with a "X" second delay after internet connection is established at login (LINUX)

Tags: linux, systemd, service

I want to use systemd to configure this, do I have to create a custom target and then custom services on it to make this happen? How do I do that?

Comment: That sounds like an XY problem - See https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault

Comment: What don't you understand about what I just wrote?

Comment: What you write can be understood, however, it is not clear what what you are trying to achieve, and what you asking for suggests this to be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 4):

You could try creating a `.service` that depends on `network-online.target` and uses `ExecStartPre` to sleep.

The dependency on `network-online.target` will mean the service is not started until networking is fully configured.

Using a sleep command in `ExecStartPre` will delay the execution of `ExecStart`, which is what would run the real program.

This is a partial `.service` file that sleeps for 10 seconds after networking is configured.

```
[Unit]
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10
```